# How to draw circles with proper anti-aliasing?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, pyglet

Following the example given in the first code snippet of [pyglet's official documentation about shapes](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/shapes.html) I clearly get a jagged edge to the circle, it is clearly not anti-aliased in any successful way on my system at least. Here's my code and a screenshot:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes

window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True)
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

circle = shapes.Circle(700, 150, 100, color=(50, 225, 30), batch=batch)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

[image]

So I am wondering whether it is so that pyglet does not directly cater for anti-aliasing with arcs, circles and lines.

And, how would you approach getting smooth circle/arc edges and smooth lines, using pyglet ― would you recommend a particular intervening (python) library for drawing smoothly-edged shapes? would you call OpenGL from [pyglet's own OpenGL bindings](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/gl.html) to smoothly accomplish it?

A related discussion from over ten years ago:
[Pyglet OpenGL drawing anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747784/pyglet-opengl-drawing-anti-aliasing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an OpenGL window with frame buffer configured  for multisampling (see [Creating an OpenGL context](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/context.html) ans [Specifying the OpenGL context properties](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/window.html#specifying-the-opengl-context-properties)):

```py
import pyglet

config = pyglet.gl.Config()
config.sample_buffers = 1
config.samples = 4

indow = pyglet.window.Window(config=config)
```